# Smartphone-style ComboBox behavior on PocketPC platform?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, pocketpc, smartphone

I develop applications for the PocketPC platform (.NET Compact Framework 2.0 and higher), and one of the problems I constantly run in to is the drop-down width for ComboBox controls is not wide enough to show very long string values.

I've run across P/Invoke methods to widen the dropdown width, but what I'd really like to have is the Smartphone-style behavior for ComboBoxes. By this, I mean the initial view is that of a Spin Control (left/right arrows that scroll through the option list), and if you click the action button it takes you to a full-screen rendition of all the options that is much easier to read.

I think I could create a custom user control to simulate this behavior on the PocketPC, but I would like to know if it's possible to get at the actual Smartphone functionality and use that. It would definitely be faster to tap into existing functionality if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, because that behavior in a ComboBox is just how the PocketPC smartphone OS handles ComboBoxes.  If you compile a smartphone app with a ComboBox and run it in regular PocketPC, the ComboBox won't behave that way (I think).

Comment: Well, that would make sense. I guess this is attributed to "physical" differences in the Windows Mobile platform as implemented on Smartphones vs. PocketPCs?

I guess I was hoping that both platforms shared the same code, and we could "trick" the PocketPC into running some Smartphone stuff.

Comment: Controls in regular Windows Mobile are just stripped-down versions of regular Windows controls, but I'm pretty sure most of the Smartphone controls were implemented separately from scratch, since they had to work without a mouse or stylus.

Comment: Don't worry, I haven't abandoned this question. I like to wait a bit to see if anyone else chimes in. But it looks like this is probably it. And provided our client approves work in this area, I'll gladly share the custom control that I build for this purpose.